# Effect of import quota on NCO, NX

Tags: supply-and-demand, exchange-rates

I'm studying loanable funds from the book "Brief Principles of Macroeconomics, 6th ed". On page 307, the effects of an import quota are explained below. It said the net export rises, but NCO doesn't change. But NX = NCO, so I really confused. Can someone explain why it is and what I understand wrong?
[image]

Comment: Please do not include screenshots of plain text and equations. Please consider revising it to be more in line with the community expectations. [We expect questions to provide evidence of prior research](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help), and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question)` provide resources to assist with revisions.